# when my VB.NET app sends email by SendGrid, Hotmail strips the line feeds

Tags: vb.net, windows, email, smtp, sendgrid

Platform: Azure VM Windows Server 2012

Language:  VB.NET 2015 windows app

My app sends out a text email with vbcrlf between the lines, through SendGrid, to a @Hotmail.com address.
If I debug.print the email message, those vbcrlf's are all there.

But then Hotmail displays the message with all the sentences jammed together without my line breaks between.

Comment: That's because your mail client can't translate the `vbcrlf` use `</br>` to break a line... Make sure the email is html and you should be good to go. The constant you are using is a carriage return line feed, the email client doesn't know this...

Comment: Using html you will also have complete control of the layout, just a thought.

Comment: Also looking at your profile/questions I would recommend replying and or accepting answers. We are here to help, if we did at some point give that credit.

Comment: Thanks.  Stackoverflow is the greatest development tool since the keyboard!

Comment: Codexer, how do I "make sure email is HTML"?

Comment: It's part of the MailMessage class: IsBodyHtml... Since you are using SendGrid try sending the email in html format. If it doesn't work check the documentation for SendGrid...they may have an equivalent property you must set.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

step 1. 
AZURE DASHBOARD > Marketplace left tab > sendgrid > Manage > Settings > Mail Settings > Convert your plain text emails to HTML = "ON "

2. The SendGrid example set it for HTML.
   For just plain text, DON'T do this:
   myMessage.Html =  Message

DO this:
myMessage.Text = Message